# Why two strings (they look the same) have different ascii codes?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have problem with string comparison. I have two strings and they have two different ASCII code:
Temat 1 - ASCII: 620
Temat 1 - ASCII: 588

Ascii is generated by this function:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
    { 
        $ascii += ord($string[$i]); 
    }
```

I think this is why my sql query gives me an empty result.
When I do this:

```
$resultsT = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "temat" AND meta_value = "'.$temat.'"', OBJECT );
```

Query result is empty.
But when i do this:

```
$resultsT = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "temat" AND meta_value = "Temat 1"', OBJECT );
```

Query is ok.

Comment: Not a solution, but you should really use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know, but safety is not my concern now. I need this working and I don't know why it is not

Comment: What is the content of `$temat` in the first query?

Comment: It is variable from $_POST, $temat = $_POST['temat'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much info in the question, but I'm guessing it's case-sensitivity in your database.  Notice that the difference in the ASCII code sum is 32, which is the difference between the upper case and lower case letters in ASCII.  So I would guess that your php code is setting $temat to the string "*t*emat 1", but the meta_value is "*T*emat 1" with an upper case "**T**".  That would account for both the ASCII code difference and the query not returning the expected results.

EDIT: <del>The new comment says that the variable $temat is set to "temat".  The problem then is that the meta_value is "Temat 1" and the query is looking for "temat".  They are not equal.  You either want to add the missing " **1**" to the post variable $temat, or else use a LIKE query to match everything that starts with the string "temat":</del>

```
post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "temat" AND meta_value like "'.$temat.'%"', OBJECT );
```

EDIT 2: The value of the post variable has not been given - I misread the code as setting it to the string "temat" when it is in fact set to the value of the post variable with the name "temat".

Comment: Yes, it is.  `print_r` from `$_POST` gives this  `Array ( [temat] => Temat 1 [priorytet] => [dzialanie] => [data_od] => [data_do] => )`

Comment: It's also possible you have an extra space at the start or end of your variable value, 32 is the ascii code for a space.  Try trimming the variable before using it in the query.

Comment: So simple as that... :) Thank you so much, you are genius! Trim solved my problems :) Thank you once again!